# Using Firebase Auth & gAPI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-api-js-client

How do I get Firebase Auth to work with Google drive api?

Using react, I have firebase auth working and google drive (gapi) both working individually but am struggling to merge the two.

With Firebase 9, it's been made easier to access Google API: `This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access Google APIs.`

My thinking is to get the token and then pass that to the gapi `.init` function. However, I'm not sure where to go after that. Any guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

```
import { getAuth, getRedirectResult, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

onst auth = getAuth();
signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
  .then((result) => {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const token = credential.accessToken;
```

My gapi implementation:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.gapi.load("client:auth2", initClient);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (authState) {
      authState.isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
    }
  }, [authState]);

  const initClient = () => {
    try {
      window.gapi.auth2
        .init({
          apiKey: "API KEY...",
          clientId:
            "CLIENT ID...",
          scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
          discoveryDocs: [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest",
          ],
        })
        .then(() => {
          const authInstance = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
          setAuthState(authInstance);
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  const signInFunction = () => {
    authState.signIn();
    updateSigninStatus();
  };

  const signOutFunction = () => {
    authState.signOut();
  };

  const updateSigninStatus = () => {
    setSigninStatus();
  };

  const setSigninStatus = async () => {
     //code...
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same thing and then I heard the Fireship guy talking about how easier it was to do it the other way around - sign in with gapi and pass credentials to Firebase.

I'm gonna share the way I did it, so you can relate to the solution and apply it to your project.

Initiate gapi using [gapi-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gapi-script) in a `gapi.js` file and export gapi instance which you will use throughout the app.

```
import { gapi } from 'gapi-script'

gapi.load('client:auth2', async () => {
  gapi.client.init({
    apiKey: <YOUR_API_KEY>,
    clientId: <YOUR_GAPI_CLIENT_ID>,
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
    discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest']
  })

  gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3', () => {})
})

export default gapi
```

Then initiate Firebase in a separate file as follows:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: <YOUR_FIREBASE_API_KEY>,
  authDomain: <YOUR_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN>,
  projectId: <YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID>,
  storageBucket: <YOUR_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET>,
  messagingSenderId: <YOUR_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID>,
  appId: <YOUR_FIREBASE_APP_ID>,
  clientId: <YOUR_FIREBASE_CLIENT_ID>,
  scopes: ['email', 'profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'],
  discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest']
}

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const firebaseAuth = getAuth(firebaseApp)

export { firebaseApp, firebaseAuth }
```

And finally, in the `auth.js` file you can define functions that will be used throughout the project. You will notice that after logging in `id_token` is being grabbed from the auth response and passed as a *credential* to `GoogleAuthProvider`.

```
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signOut, signInWithCredential } from 'firebase/auth'
import { firebaseAuth } from './firebaseConfig'
import gapi from '../gapi'

/**
 * Sign in using gapi and pass credential to Firebase
 * Needs to be configured in https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/<YOUR_PROJECT>/authentication/providers
 * by passing Web SDK Configuration (Web client ID and Web client secret) which can be found on
 * https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=<YOUR_PROJECT> under OAuth 2.0 Client IDs
 */
const signInPopup = async () => {
  try {
    const googleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
    const googleUser = await googleAuth.signIn()

    const token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(token)

    const response = await signInWithCredential(firebaseAuth, credential)

    // store user
  } catch (error) {
    // clean user from store
    console.error('signInPopup (firebase/auth.js)', error)
  }
}

const signOutUser = async () => {
  try {
    await gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut()
    console.log('User is signed out from gapi.')

    await signOut(firebaseAuth)
    console.log('User is signed out from firebase.')

    // clean user from store
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('signOutUser (firebase/auth.js): ', error)
  }
}

export { signInPopup, signOutUser }
```

However, you should be careful with this approach, since you will have to log out user from both services at once.

Answer (score 1):

Lazar Kulasevic answer was fine before gapi.client.init became deprecated. Now you should use GIS as recommended in https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview

Here is a sample of Angular code that use firebase and gapi :

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
        <app-root></app-root>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

In a auth.service.ts file :

```
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/gapi/index.d.ts" />
declare const google: any;

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {

    login() {
        const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
            client_id: environment.clientId,
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
            callback: (authResponse: { access_token: any }) => {
                // initialize gapi
                gapi.load('client', () => {
                    gapi.client
                        .init({}) // don't provide any param
                        .then(() => {
                            // Load the Calendar API discovery document for exemple 
                            gapi.client
                                .load('https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest')
                                .then(async () => {
                                    console.log('gapi calendar loaded ');
                                });
                        })
                        .catch((reason) => console.log('gapi.client.init failed', reason));
                });

                // initialize firebase auth
                const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null,authResponse.access_token);
                signInWithCredential(getAuth(), credential)
                    .then((auth: UserCredential) => {
                        ...
                    })
                    .catch((error) => this.#subject$.error(error));
                }
        });
        client.requestAccessToken();
    }
...
```

npm install the "@types/gapi" to get gapi reference

I suggest you read https://fireship.io/lessons/google-calendar-api-with-firebase/ and https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis